# Create custom block with node title?

Tags: blocks, theming

I would like to be able to use a region which is to contain the title of the current node. In the default theme the title is output in the main content, but I want it in this custom region instead. But I cannot find a block for the node title. Can I create it?

Comment: It's not a real answer in that it doesn't involve a block, but [The Scary Render Array](http://cocoate.com/ddbook/scary-render-array) might give you an alternative method.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the title from the node.tpl.php and create a new block with the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$node = node_load(arg(1));
print $node->title;
?>
```

Enable visibility only on view node pages.

[CCK Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/cck_blocks) is a very handy module for these things, but unfortunately the node title isn't listed as an element in display mode.

[EDIT]

If you are on D7 and you are using Omega theme, [Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta) module should work for you. Check specifically Delta Blocks module from that package.

Comment: Ok, I have never created a block in code so far, I have only selected blocks available. So where do I create a block, in a new php file?

Comment: First step: make sure the PHP filter module is enabled. Second: create a new block and elect "PHP" as filter input and paste the code from my message.

Comment: I just remembered of another module that might help you. Check my post above.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new block with the hook_block_ ... hooks.

Here's a block [example](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/block_example!block_example.module/7) how to do this. In [hook_block_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7), you can define the node title in `$block['subject']`.

Have a look to the code sample from Ivanhoe123 how to get the node title.